How to obviate incompatibility of d3.js versions?
If I use d3@7 I have nice labeling but no circle with toltip moves along the line as it supposed by code. A piece of circle is available in the upper left corner.
If I use d3@6 I have absurd labeling and circle and tooltip with strange coordinates in it stick on the middle of the line.
Other versions do not work at all.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatable" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
    <script type="module">
      // Curved line declaration
      const data = [{xpoint: 10, ypoint: 0.2},
            {xpoint: 4, ypoint: 1},
            {xpoint: 3, ypoint: 2},
            {xpoint: 2, ypoint: 3},
            {xpoint: 1, ypoint: 10}];
// Declare the chart dimensions and margins.
const width = 640;
const height = 400;
const marginTop = 20;
const marginRight = 20;
const marginBottom = 30;
const marginLeft = 40;

// Declare the x (horizontal position) scale.
      const x = d3.scaleLog()
        .domain([0.2, 60])
    .range([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

// Declare the y (vertical position) scale.
const y = d3.scaleLog()
    .domain([0.1, 100])
    .range([height - marginBottom, marginTop]);

  // Declare the line generator.
      const line = d3.line()
    .x((d) => x(d.xpoint))
    .y((d) => y(d.ypoint))
        .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5));
      
// Create the SVG container.
const svg = d3.create("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
      

// Add the x-axis.
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add the y-axis.
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Append a path for the line.
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line(data));

 // This allows to find the closest X index of the mouse:
  const bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.xpoint; }).left;

  // Create the circle that travels along the curve of chart
  const focus = svg
    .append('g')
    .append('circle')
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr('r', 8.5)
      .style("opacity", 0)

 // Create the text that travels along the curve of chart
  const focusText = svg
    .append('g')
    .append('text')
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("text-anchor", "left")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")

 // Create a rect on top of the svg area: this rectangle recovers mouse position
  svg.append('rect')
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .on('mouseover', mouseover)
    .on('mousemove', mousemove)
    .on('mouseout', mouseout);
      
// What happens when the mouse move -> show the annotations at the right positions.
  function mouseover() {
      focus.style("opacity", 1)
      focusText.style("opacity",1)
  };

function mousemove() {
    // recover coordinate we need
    const x0 = x.invert(d3.pointer(this)[0]);
    // console.log(x0)
    const i = bisect(data, x0, 1);
    //console.log(i)
    const selectedData = data[i]
    focus
      .attr("cx", x(selectedData.xpoint))
      .attr("cy", y(selectedData.ypoint))
    focusText
      .html("x:" + selectedData.xpoint + "  -  " + "y:" + selectedData.ypoint)
      .attr("x", x(selectedData.xpoint)+15)
    .attr("y", y(selectedData.ypoint))
};
      function mouseout() {
    focus.style("opacity", 0)
      focusText.style("opacity", 0)
      };

    
// Append the SVG element.
      container.append(svg.node());

</script>
</body>
</html>



A couple issues:
1 - d3.pointer(this) is no longer valid.  this used to represent the event, now the event is passed as an argument to the mousemove callback:
function mousemove(event) {
    const x0 = x.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
    ...

2 - your bisector function is wrong.  Your data is not sorted ascending.  To handle the descending sort, the correct function would be:
const bisect = d3.bisector(function (d, x) {
    return x - d.xpoint;
}).left;

Putting it all together:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatable" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
    <script type="module">
      // Curved line declaration
      const data = [
        { xpoint: 10, ypoint: 0.2 },
        { xpoint: 4, ypoint: 1 },
        { xpoint: 3, ypoint: 2 },
        { xpoint: 2, ypoint: 3 },
        { xpoint: 1, ypoint: 10 },
      ];
      // Declare the chart dimensions and margins.
      const width = 640;
      const height = 400;
      const marginTop = 20;
      const marginRight = 20;
      const marginBottom = 30;
      const marginLeft = 40;

      // Declare the x (horizontal position) scale.
      const x = d3
        .scaleLog()
        .domain([0.2, 60])
        .range([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

      // Declare the y (vertical position) scale.
      const y = d3
        .scaleLog()
        .domain([0.1, 100])
        .range([height - marginBottom, marginTop]);

      // Declare the line generator.
      const line = d3
        .line()
        .x((d) => x(d.xpoint))
        .y((d) => y(d.ypoint))
        .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5));

      // Create the SVG container.
      const svg = d3.create('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

      // Add the x-axis.
      svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // Add the y-axis.
      svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      // Append a path for the line.
      svg
        .append('path')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
        .attr('d', line(data));

      // This allows to find the closest X index of the mouse:
      const bisect = d3.bisector(function (d, x) {
        return x - d.xpoint;
      }).left;

      // Create the circle that travels along the curve of chart
      const focus = svg
        .append('g')
        .append('circle')
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('r', 8.5)
        .style('opacity', 0);

      // Create the text that travels along the curve of chart
      const focusText = svg
        .append('g')
        .append('text')
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
        .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle');

      // Create a rect on top of the svg area: this rectangle recovers mouse position
      svg
        .append('rect')
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .style('pointer-events', 'all')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .on('mouseover', mouseover)
        .on('mousemove', mousemove)
        .on('mouseout', mouseout);

      // What happens when the mouse move -> show the annotations at the right positions.
      function mouseover() {
        focus.style('opacity', 1);
        focusText.style('opacity', 1);
      }

      function mousemove(event) {
        const x0 = x.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
        const i = bisect(data, x0);
        const selectedData = data[i];
        if (!selectedData) return;
        focus
          .attr('cx', x(selectedData.xpoint))
          .attr('cy', y(selectedData.ypoint));
        focusText
          .html(
            'x:' + selectedData.xpoint + '  -  ' + 'y:' + selectedData.ypoint
          )
          .attr('x', x(selectedData.xpoint) + 15)
          .attr('y', y(selectedData.ypoint));
      }
      function mouseout() {
        focus.style('opacity', 0);
        focusText.style('opacity', 0);
      }

      // Append the SVG element.
      container.append(svg.node());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




As I recall my struggling the first issue, it is d3.mouse(this) is no longer valid. May you show how to change step parameter, so to speak, between consecutive tooltips? Thank you.

In versions prior to V6 this was the event in the callback.  In later versions this is the element on which the event happens.  And I don't understand your follow-up question.

Thank you for explaining "this". My follow-up question was as to obtain coordinates along the curve with getTotalLength and getPointAtLength methods. Just learn of them.
